# Is the data transfer format JSON between client and server?

Tags: json, node.js, pug

A small doubt regarding data transfer between client and server using JSON.
Here is a node.js server script which sends the data to client.

Is the  below server script already sending the data in json format or do I have to make some changes in the script ? Basically I want to send data in json format between the server and the client.

```
app.get('/playground', function(req, res) {
    AM.getAllCategories( function(e, categories){            
       res.render('playground', { title : 'Categories List', cats : categories });
}

AM.getAllCategories queries mongodb and returns something like this
[{"name":"Electronics"},{"name":"Real Estate"}] 

//form( method="post")#sender-form.form-inline.well.span6
    form( method="post")#category-form
      h1
      p#sub1.subheading Select a category
      //hr
      div.container(style='margin:20px')
        table.table.table-bordered.table-striped
          thead
            tr
              //th(style='width:40px') #
              th(style='width:180px') Name
              th(style='width:200px') Location
              th(style='width:180px') Username
              //th Account Created
          tbody
            - for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++)
              tr
                td
                  a(href='/home/')= cats[i].name
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is probably sending response in HTML (regular web page). To make it output JSON, try changing this:

```
app.get('/playground', function(req, res) {
  AM.getAllCategories(function(e, categories){   
   // TODO: also, check for error here ("e" variable)         
   res.send(categories);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send JSON to a client, either use `res.send()` with an object, or use `res.json()`. `res.render()` renders a view, and will not create JSON.

```
AM.getAllCategories(function(err, categories) {   
  if (err) {
    // if there's an error, send a 500 and the error in JSON
    res.json(500, err);
    return;
  }

  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // probably unneeded
  res.send(categories);

  // or the JSON function
  res.send(categories);
  res.send(200, categories); // send a status code
}
```